# javax.servlet.http.httpservletrequest cannot be resolved after upgrading spring boot version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Recently I have upgraded the spring boot version of my project from 2.5.3 to 2.5.12 and 2.6.6. In both versions, the same issue appear.

*javax.servlet.http.httpservletrequest cannot be resolved*

I tried adding the dependency in my pom.xml as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, the other issues came out after solving the issue above.

*The import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication cannot be resolved
The import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication cannot be resolved
The import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties cannot be resolved*

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: I have seen similar Problems with the latest spirng versions. Is your Spring cloud dependency updated to "2021.0.1" ?

Comment: @GJohannes Yes exactly.

Comment: @KLRay If you provide some more information or code snippet it would be helpful analyse.